# How does ionic serve --all work?

Tags: rest, client, server, ionic-framework

How does this command work?

```
ionic serve --all
```

Can I access the application from a browser on another machine in my LAN, or anywhere on the web?

Comment: you can access it from any device connected to your LAN, Open your mobile browser, and type in the IP, PS I should tel you, if you have plugins installed, plugins wont load on browser and  you might end up with blank screen.

Comment: How do i know which IP adress to open on a mobile browser?

Comment: when you do ionic serve , it actually shows on which IP address its running on. If you are on windows you can check it by running command prompt and typing  "ipconfig" and get the IP address from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `ionic serve` creates a NodeJS server on your machine. This means that it may be accessible from anywhere if you configure well your router.

However, where have you seen that parameter `--all`

I see only the following

```
serve [options] ...........................  Start a local development server for app dev/testing
  [--consolelogs|-c]  .................  Print app console logs to Ionic CLI
  [--serverlogs|-s]  ..................  Print dev server logs to Ionic CLI
  [--port|-p]  ........................  Dev server HTTP port (8100 default)
  [--livereload-port|-r]  .............  Live Reload port (35729 default)
  [--nobrowser|-b]  ...................  Disable launching a browser
  [--nolivereload|-d]  ................  Do not start live reload
  [--noproxy|-x]  .....................  Do not add proxies
  [--address]  ........................  Use specific address or return with failure
  [--browser|-w]  .....................  Specifies the browser to use (safari, firefox, chrome)
  [--browseroption|-o]  ...............  Specifies a path to open to (/#/tab/dash)
  [--lab|-l]  .........................  Test your apps on multiple screen sizes and platform types
```